# SSIS package security issue during connection creation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, package

I have create SSIS package for deployment. SSIS package is executed successfully. There are two database servers. 1 server is connected with my package connections and i am deploying on the other server using sql jobs. SQL jobs gives error when try to create  connection with other server.

Following is the error.

```
Date,Source,Severity,Step ID,Server,Job Name,Step Name,Notifications,Message,Duration,Sql Severity,Sql Message ID,Operator Emailed,Operator Net sent,Operator Paged,Retries Attempted
08/26/2013 04:02:19,XIPPackage,Error,0,DEVELOPMENT\PORTFOLIOCENTER,XIPPackage,(Job outcome),,The job failed.  The Job was invoked by User test.  The last step to run was step 1 (XIPPackageStep).,00:00:00,0,0,,,,0
08/26/2013 04:02:19,XIPPackage,Error,1,DEVELOPMENT\PORTFOLIOCENTER,XIPPackage,XIPPackageStep,,Executed as user: DEVELOPMENT\SYSTEM. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.1600.1 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started:  4:02:19 AM  Error: 2013-08-26 04:02:19.55     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: TestXIPPackage Connection manager "Source"     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Login failed for user 'TestCAPITAL\DEVELOPMENT$'.".  End Error  Error: 2013-08-26 04:02:19.55     Code: 0xC020801C     Source: Populate Tradeblotter Staging Load Staging [2633]     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Source" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.  End Error  Error: 2013-08-26 04:02:19.55     Code: 0xC0047017     Source: Populate Tradeblotter Staging SSIS.Pipeline     Description: component "Load Staging" (2633) failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.  End Error  Error: 2013-08-26 04:02:19.55     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: Populate Tradeblotter Staging SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error  Error: 2013-08-26 04:02:19.55     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: Populate Tradeblotter Staging      Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  4:02:19 AM  Finished: 4:02:19 AM  Elapsed:  0.499 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.,00:00:00,0,0,,,,0
08/26/2013 03:49:43,XIPPackage,Error,0,DEVELOPMENT\PORTFOLIOCENTER,XIPPackage,(Job outcome),,The job failed.  The Job was invoked by User **hidden**.  The last step to run was step 1 (XIPPackageStep).,00:00:00,0,0,,,,0
08/26/2013 03:49:43,XIPPackage,Error,1,DEVELOPMENT\PORTFOLIOCENTER,XIPPackage,XIPPackageStep,,Executed as user: DEVELOPMENT\SYSTEM. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.1600.1 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started:  3:49:43 AM  Error: 2013-08-26 03:49:43.38     Code: 0xC0016016     Source:       Description: Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password" with error 0x8009000B "Key not valid for use in specified state.". You may not be authorized to access this information. This error occurs when there is a cryptographic error. Verify that the correct key is available.  End Error  Error: 2013-08-26 03:49:43.40     Code: 0xC0016016     Source:       Description: Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password" with error 0x8009000B "Key not valid for use in specified state.". You may not be authorized to access this information. This error occurs when there is a cryptographic error. Verify that the correct key is available.  End Error  Error: 2013-08-26 03:49:43.82     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: TestXIPPackage Connection manager "Source"     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Login failed for user 'TEstCAPITAL\DEVELOPMENT$'.".  End Error  Error: 2013-08-26 03:49:43.82     Code: 0xC020801C     Source: Populate Tradeblotter Staging Load Staging [2633]     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Source" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.  End Error  Error: 2013-08-26 03:49:43.82     Code: 0xC0047017     Source: Populate Tradeblotter Staging SSIS.Pipeline     Description: component "Load Staging" (2633) failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.  End Error  Error: 2013-08-26 03:49:43.82     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: Populate Tradeblotter Staging SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error  Error: 2013-08-26 03:49:43.82     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: Populate Tradeblotter Staging      Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  3:49:43 AM  Finished: 3:49:43 AM  Elapsed:  0.499 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.,00:00:00,0,0,,,,0
```

I have tried with do not save sensitive data but not worked.

Any idea how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried with do not save sensitive data but not worked.

Please post the error message. You will avoid a lot of hassles if you don't put sensitive data (passwords) in your SSIS packages. You will also avoid hassles if you never write *not work* and always provide the error message.

With regards to your errors:

> Login failed for user 'Test\DEVELOPMENT$'

To fix this you need to add the windows users 'Test\DEVELOPMENT$' as a login to the required database and ensure that it has required access to the database. Alternatively set the SQL Job up to use a windows user that does have access. I can explain further if you wish.

> Description: Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password"

To avoid this you should:

1. Only use windows authentication (not SQL Server authentication)
2. Use 'Do Not Save Sensitive Data' (hence why I need to know the error)